# Blue wire is used on furnace, but not thermostat

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

When I looked at the wires behind the thermostat, the blue wire wasn’t used. However when I look at the furnace, the blue wire is connected. I’m not sure if I should use that as the C wire. I did try it anyway, but still didn’t work. Using Honeywell T9.

There was nothing plugged into the c wire port, and I do have the c wire adapter. Not sure if I still need to use it at this point. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: blue wire connected to what?

Comment: Can you post photos of how the blue wire is connected at your furnace, as well as the wiring diagram for your furnace for that matter?

Comment: I had a new furnace installed last summer. My HVAC guy wired the _furnace_ for a more modern, C wire setup, but the stat used the blue for the 2nd stage of a 2 stage heater. When I first called for heat this fall, I got none, and it blew a fuse in the furnace. Took him a little while to realize his initial mistake & properly wire the furnace to match my stat. **TL;DR:** Make sure the blue wire is connected to the proper place in the furnace before assuming it's safe to use as a C wire. Pictures and make/model of the furnace will help a lot.